# (Laravel) How to total the integer column and send to the another table?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How do I sum the quantity with same cycle_id, type and user_id from the `feeds` table and the sum of the quantity, cycle_id, type and user_id will be passed to the `inventories` table?

`feeds` table

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->date('date_input');
    $table->string('delivery_number');  
    $table->string('type');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->unsignedInteger('cycle_id');  
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
```

`inventories` table

```
 $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('overall_quantity');
            $table->unsignedInteger('cycle_id');  
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
```

The sum of quantity will pass to the overall_quantity.
The type from `feeds` table will pass to the type from the `inventories` table.
The cycle_id from `feeds` table will pass to the cycle_id from the `inventories` table.
The user_id from `feeds` table will pass to the user_id from the `inventories` table.

If the is entry not exist in inventories table, it will create but when the entry is exist feom the `inventories` table, it will add.

This is my code

FeedController.php

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

               //validate
               $this->validate($request, array(
                'date_input' => 'required|date',
                'delivery_number' => 'required|numeric',
                'type' => 'required|max:255',
                'quantity' => 'required|numeric'
             ) );
             $input= Carbon::parse($request->get('date_input'));
             $cycle = Cycle::where('date_of_loading','<=',$input)
             ->where('date_of_harvest','>=',$input)
             ->first();

             $cycle_id =$cycle->id ?? 0;

        $feed = Feed::create([
            'date_input' => request('date_input'),
            'delivery_number' => request('delivery_number'),
            'type' => request('type'),
            'quantity' => request('quantity'),
            'cycle_id'     => $cycle_id,
           'user_id'     => Auth::id()

        ]);

        return $feed;

        $overall_quantity = Feed::where('cycle_id','=',$cycle_id)
                            ->where('type','=',$request->get('type'))
                            ->sum('quantity');

        Inventory::firstOrCreate([
            'overall_quantity' => $overall_quantity, 
            'type' => request('type'), 
            'cycle_id' => $cycle_id,
            ]);
    }
```

but it didn't work
When i add data in `feeds` table, the `inventories` table is still empty.

---

### New problem

My feed history

[image]

My `inventories` table

[image]

it should be the id 1 will be 144 but it create new entry. pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you ran the `Inventory::firstOrCreate([...])` command you returned `$feed`.

Just remove the `return` statement.

```
// return $feed;

$overall_quantity = Feed::where('cycle_id','=',$cycle_id)
                    ->where('type','=',$request->get('type'))
                    ->sum('quantity');

Inventory::firstOrCreate([    
//Add unique field combo to match here
 'type' => request('type'), 
 'cycle_id' => $cycle_id,
],[ 'overall_quantity' => $overall_quantity ]);
```

Comment: i have new problem